# Word list capacity/efficiency on NAO Robot

Tags: nao-robot

I'm using a weather API to have the NAO robot tell the weather of any city in the world. I need NAO to listen for a large list of cities. I've used a SQLite DB as well as trying a JSON file with subsequent parsing but it takes too long to load the list into the vocabulary for speech recognition. I can shorten the list by regions but is there a way to efficiently load a large amount of vocabulary?

Here is an example I've tried with success but the delay is about 12 seconds (which is too long):

```
import sqlite3 as lite
connectionString = "/home/nao/USCities.db"
myState = "Alabama"
con = lite.connect(connectionString)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT cityState FROM USCitiesTable LIMIT 2000")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    d = [[s.encode('ascii') for s in list] for list in rows]
    listofStrings = map(''.join, d)
    vocabulary = listofStrings
self.asr.setVocabulary(vocabulary, False)
self.memory.subscribeToEvent("WordRecognized", self.getName(), "onWordRecognized")
self.hasSubscribed = True
```

Comment: When you say a large, is it something like more than 100 words ? if yes, then it could be long and moreover, it won't be very efficient. Also are you sure it's the setVocabulary that takes all words and not the map or ...

Comment: It is a long list - 45,000 cities. It is the setVocabulary piece that takes so long. The map command takes less than a second. Thx for helping.

Comment: I would have say t's a bad idea to try to use the embedded speech recognition on a so long list, as I'm quite sure it won't give you good results. However if it works fine, then inform me. As I would happilly change my statement.

Comment: The accuracy is excellent but the time is quite unacceptable. I've made a workaround using smaller subsets but it definitely loses the coolness factor of retrieving data on any and every city. Others have used the QiChat formats with some success but not to this degree. Thanks for help!

Comment: That's a great news. usually we're using the remote speech recognition for that, but it requires wifi and subs/licences... So your methods, looks better.

Comment: HAve you tried: setWordListAsVocabulary ? and also perhaps to compile a grammar that could be loaded faster once created ? also working with context or slot. (never test it myself). Will try to find a specialist, stay tuned...

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try it out. Let me know what you find.